# is there any equivalent code that get buckets from google storage faster

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, boto

this the code I'm using, is there anyway to make it run faster:

```
src_uri = boto.storage_uri(bucket, google_storage)
for obj in src_uri.get_bucket():
    f.write('%s\n' % (obj.name))
```

Comment: can you give me how to get just the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example where it pays to use the underlying Google Cloud Storage API more directly, using the [Google API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) to consume the [RESTful HTTP API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/). With this approach, it is possible to use [request batching](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch) to retrieve the names of all objects in a single HTTP request (thereby reducing the extra HTTP request overhead) as well as to use field projection with the [objects.get](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get) operation (by setting `&fields=name`) to obtain a [partial response](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/performance#partial-response) so that you aren't sending all the other fields and data over the network (or waiting for retrieval of unnecessary data on the backend).

Code for this would look like:

```
def get_credentials():
   # Your code goes here... checkout the oauth2client documentation:
   # http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client-module.html
   # Or look at some of the existing samples for how to do this

def get_cloud_storage_service(credentials):
   return discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

def get_objects(cloud_storage, bucket_name, autopaginate=False):
   result = []
   # Actually, it turns out that request batching isn't needed in this
   # example, because the objects.list() operation returns not just
   # the URL for the object, but also its name, as well. If it had returned
   # just the URL, then that would be a case where we'd need such batching.
   projection = 'nextPageToken,items(name,selfLink)'
   request = cloud_storage.objects().list(bucket=bucket_name, fields=projection)
   while request is not None:
     response = request.execute()
     result.extend(response.items)
     if autopaginate:
        request = cloud_storage.objects().list_next(request, response)
     else:
        request = None
   return result

def main():
  credentials = get_credentials()
  cloud_storage = get_cloud_storage_service(credentials)
  bucket = # ... your bucket name ...
  for obj in get_objects(cloud_storage, bucket, autopaginate=True):
     print 'name=%s, selfLink=%s' % (obj.name, obj.selfLink)
```

You may find the [Google Cloud Storage Python Example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-python-samples) and other [API Client Library Examples](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/samples/samples) helpful in figuring out how to do this. There are also a number of YouTube videos on the [Google Developers channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw) such as [Accessing Google APIs: Common code walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-gBeC9Y9cE) that provide walkthroughs.

Comment: For credentials is the API key sufficient ??

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount. It describes exactly what you need, including sample Python code for how to create the credentials object, depending on where this code is running.